# ElasticSerach search for same id in multiple nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a mapping that looks like this for ElasticSearch 2.2:

```
PUT /index/test_type/_mapping
{
  "test_type":{
       "properties":{
            "nested_one":{
                 "type":"nested",
                 "properties":{
                     "some_id":{
                         "type":"string"
                     }
                 }
             },
             "nested_two":{
                 "type":"nested",
                 "properties":{
                     "some_id":{
                         "type":"string"
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
     }
```

I have to create a search for some_id that would appear as a property of both nested_one and nested_two inside the object test_type (and yes I have to keep this test_type wrapper).

So, the query would be something like if test_type.nested_one.some_id = 1 OR test_type.nested_two.some_id = 1 return elasticId (notice some_id is the same here).

I found documentation for searching nested data types and with 'or', but nothing that can search for the same property in multiple nested objects inside a object via 'or'.  My question is, is this possible with this mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the mappings

```
PUT index_name1
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {},
            "filter": {}
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "test_type":{
       "properties":{
            "nested_one":{
                 "type":"nested",
                 "properties":{
                     "some_id":{
                         "type":"string"
                     }
                 }
             },
             "nested_two":{
                 "type":"nested",
                 "properties":{
                     "some_id":{
                         "type":"string"
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
     }
    }
}
```

Following is the document i indexed

```
POST index_name1/test_type
{
  "nested_one" : [{
    "some_id" : 78
  },
  {
    "some_id" : 80
  },{
    "some_id" : 100
  }],
  "nested_two" : [{
    "some_id" : 79
  },
  {
    "some_id" : 80
  },{
    "some_id" : 101
  }]
}
```

Following is the query

```
  POST index_name1/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "nested": {
                    "path": "nested_one",
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "nested_one.some_id": {
                                "value": 101
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "nested_two",
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "nested_two.some_id": {
                                "value": 101
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Reponse

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0.9808292,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index_name1",
        "_type": "test_type",
        "_id": "AVn788XeNIJY0Ao5vbA8",
        "_score": 0.9808292,
        "_source": {
          "nested_one": [
            {
              "some_id": 78
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 100
            }
          ],
          "nested_two": [
            {
              "some_id": 79
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 101
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index_name1",
        "_type": "test_type",
        "_id": "AVn8BMr_NIJY0Ao5vbA_",
        "_score": 0.9808292,
        "_source": {
          "title": "harley harley harley",
          "nested_one": [
            {
              "some_id": 78
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 100
            }
          ],
          "nested_two": [
            {
              "some_id": 79
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 101
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index_name1",
        "_type": "test_type",
        "_id": "AVn8BKlmNIJY0Ao5vbA-",
        "_score": 0.9808292,
        "_source": {
          "title": "harley harley",
          "nested_one": [
            {
              "some_id": 78
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 100
            }
          ],
          "nested_two": [
            {
              "some_id": 79
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 101
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps
Thanks

Comment: very very close I think, but nested_two.some_id and nested_one.some_id are the same id of 80.  So I should get a hit if some_id: 80 is in EITHER nested_one or nested_two!

Comment: yes it will exactly work this way. you can run the query with 101 instead of 80

Comment: @arturobelano edited the post with changed query and response as well. thanks

Comment: Went ahead and accepted the answer, but just one more question (and thank you).  In the post we have to wrap (POST index_name1/test_type) it in test_type{...} I think this affects the query.

Comment: yes wrapping this will search for documents only with type test_type, if you have only one type in your index then it doesn't effect the query.  For multiple types in index adding test_type will scope the query to that particular type only

Comment: Tested everything, wrapping the post to POST index_name1/test_type in test_type{..} breaks the search query.